# Open windows form application from a link in locally hosted website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, emgucv

I have created a windows form application that is a face recogniser using EMGU CV. I also have a website which is locally hosted on my laptop, made using ASP.NET MVC4. I want a link on my website which ,upon clicking, opens the facial recognition software. Is it possible to do it? Do I have to create a setup of application and install it to do this or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effort involved to do what you are asking for is almost certainly much higher than you are willing to take on.  I'm only aware of two possible approaches.  The first is to use the Microsoft Click-Once technology, which streams binaries through to the client.  However, the binaries arrive at the client very untrusted, so you need to do quite a bit of work on the client to set up the appropriate permissions.  The other approach is to associate your image recognition form with one of the safe MIME types, and then stream out a file of that MIME type.  If your application is the default application for that type, it will be called to handle that file.

Comment: is it possible to create .exe of the application and then call it from the webpage?

Comment: No.  If a web page could call some arbitrary executable on the client machine, hackers would be able to do all kinds of unpleasant things.  Browsers hide any hint about what .exe's live on the client machine from the javascript or back-end server code.